# Можно ли реализовать в Hibernate?

Tags: java, база-данных, hibernate, model

База данных содержит в себе множество одинаковых таблиц которые отличаются только именем.
Можно ли создать модель в Hibernate, которая может работать с несколькими таблицами ?

Answer (score 0):

1. Нет, одну модель для множества таблиц создать нельзя, но можно максимально снизить количество дублирования кода за счёт механизмов наследования классов:

   ```
   @MappedSuperclass
   public abstract class GenericEntity {

     @Id
     @Column(name = "id")
     private Long id;

     @Column(name = "some_date")
     private Date dateField;

     @Column(name = "some_varchar")
     private String stringField;

   //get-еры, set-еры
   }

   @Entity
   @Table(name = "table1")
   public class Table1 extends GenericEntity {
   }

   @Entity
   @Table(name = "table2")
   public class Table2 extends GenericEntity {
   }
   ```

   В этом примере базовый класс GenericEntity содержит описание всех полей одинаковых таблиц, классы наследники определяют только имя таблицы, а состав полей наследуют от GenericEntity.
2. Вам стоит задуматься о оптимальности структуры БД. Зачем плодить идентичные таблицы, если можно хранить всё в одной, и завести поле некоего признака, указывающего к какому типу относится та или иная запись в таблице.